# ZF_FORM: How to add some view template for form element?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-decorators

I created element in form object:

```
function createElement()
{
    $template = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('field');
    $template->addDecorator('ViewScript', array('placement' => 'prepend', 'viewModule' => 'admin', 'viewScript' => 'values.phtml'))

   $this->addElement($template);
}

function setViewTemplate($values)
{
     $view = new Zend_View();
     $view->setScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/scripts/');
     $view->assign('values', $values);

     $this->getElement('field')->setView($view);
}
```

But in the view script 'values.phtml' I cannot get access to values like $this->values.
What I'm doing wrong here?
I know that it would be good to add own decorator, but it is interesting to use zends' decorators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Zend Framework Documentation: [Standard Form Decorators Shipped With Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardDecorators.html) Section 
**Zend_Form_Decorator_ViewScript**

> Additionally, all options passed to
>   the decorator via setOptions() that
>   are not used internally (such as
>   placement, separator, etc.) are passed
>   to the view script as view variables.

```
function setViewTemplate($values)
{
     $this->getElement('field')
          ->getDecorator('ViewScript')
          ->setOptions('values', $values);
}
```

Comment: yup, it works also! It is better solution than setAttrib. But both ways are obtained at the same time. Thx everybody for help!

Answer (score 1):

you can reslove it with using attribs

```
$template->setAttrib('key', 'value');
```

and in template

```
<?php echo $this->element->getAttrib('key'); ?>
```